# Как за счёт grid зафиксировать header и footer и другие какие-нибудь элементы

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, grid

Сделал такую верстку, но не сдвигается header, и не показывается footer.

```
body {

  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  --main-spacing: 15px 5px 10px 5px;
  --header-footer-spacing: 10px 5px;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "main"
    "footer";
}
.header {
  grid-area: header;
}
main {
  grid-area: main;
  padding: var(--main-spacing);
  overflow: auto;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(0, 600px) 1fr;
}
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="./sty.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">header</div>
      <div class="main">куча текста</div>
      <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```